# Hadoop ResourceManager does not start with ./start-yarn.sh

Tags: logging, hadoop, amazon-ec2, hadoop-yarn

I try to start hadoop's yarn in EC2 like

```
$ ./start-yarn.sh
```

and I get the following message

```
starting yarn daemons
starting resourcemanager, logging to /home/ubuntu/library/hadoop/hadoop-2.2.0/logs/yarn-ubuntu-resourcemanager-ip-x-x-x-x.out
localhost: Warning: Permanently added the ECDSA host key for IP address 'x.x.x.x' to the list of known hosts.
localhost: starting nodemanager, logging to /home/ubuntu/library/hadoop/hadoop-2.2.0/logs/yarn-ubuntu-nodemanager-ip-x-x-x-x.out
```

When I try `$ jps` I do not see a ResourceManager running.
When I check the `yarn-ubuntu-resourcemanager-ip-x-x-x-x.out` file, I see,

```
ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 7862
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 7862
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

PS: I have added the ip, x.x.x.x localhost to the list of hosts in `/etc/hosts`

How should I debug this?

Comment: Look at `yarn-ubuntu-resourcemanager-*.log` not `.out`

Comment: @RamananR *.log file shows one very old log record and does not get updated at all.

Comment: Are there other `*-resourcemanager-*` logs?

Comment: @RamananR No. There is only one *-resourcemanager-*.log